# MySQL Version Control

Tags: mysql, version-control

I am wanting to do some basic version control with my mysql database structure. I am not worried about the contents of the database, I just want to track any new tables added, tables altered, and tables deleted.

Is there a simple application that could do this all automagically? (Needs to run on a Linux envirnment)

I have looked at a few, such as PHPMyVersion, but it is no longer being developed, and not quite what I was looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783834/mysql-version-control-subversion

Comment: Had a look at that already, but it's not quite what I am looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like [MySQLdiff](http://www.mysqldiff.org/) is what you want.

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just got Navicat Premium and saw that it is able to do it too. Very nice easy to interface. A+

Comment: We use a program called ORM Designer to create our model and we generate our doctrine 2 classes from this model. It works great. This model is just XML so you can put it in SVN, GIT, what have you.