# Database modeling software with non-binary file format?

Tags: mysql, version-control, file-format, mysql-workbench, database-design

Do you know a database modeling software whose the file format can safely be tracked by a VCS without always creating conflicts ? (i.e. a non-binary file format.) It would be great if the software worked on Linux and MacOS also.

It would be even better if the file format could be diffed easily.

**Edit:**

I am currently using MySQL Workbench and am satisfied with it, however its binary file format keeps creating conflicts in the VCS, and using it is a pain because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only avaiable tool I know is [WWW SQL Designer](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/).

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is answered here:  [MySQL Version Control - Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783834/mysql-version-control-subversion)

Comment: Liquibase looks awesome. Unfortunately it seems that the gui has never gone beyond _technology preview_ and is not even available for download

Answer (score 1):

I use [microOLAP](http://www.microolap.com/) for MySQL database design. It's a windows application unfortunately (I'm a Linux+Mac user mysql too), but it works like a charm. It generates XML out of the database schema, so it can safely be imported into any VCS.
Otherwise, you can try Dia on Linux as well. It's not as advanced as microOLAP, but it does have limited ER-diagram designing possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately Dia is not great as a db modeling tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is Workbench's predecessor, [DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/downloads.php) which saves XML files and has Windows and Linux versions.

Alternatively, you could use pre-commit and post-update hooks to convert your Workbench model files before a commit and recreate them after an update and put the non-binary data into version control. However, you would still have to be careful when merging.

- Pre-commit: Unzip the model file, store the XML and a SQLite dump
- Post-update: Recreate the SQLite database and generate model file.

Comment: Note that I've experienced some crashes with DBDesigner in the past  - as I did with Workbench; however, development stopped when Workbench came out. So, save frequently if you decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "MySQL Workbench"

Comment: This is what I am currently using. The file format is two zipped files: a XML doc and a SQLite db. In the end this is a binary format.

Comment: You can .dump a SQLite schema. But that's an extra manual step. Might be worth the trouble, though.